# Incoherent results on Oracle Spatial Query with SDO_CONTAINS

Tags: oracle-spatial

If I run the following query:

```
select zona
 , fid
 , count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z join geo_bcn_illes i 
  on SDO_CONTAINS(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
where zona='z01'and fid = 53
group by zona, fid
```

I got the following results:

```
 zona   fid count(*)
 z01    53  34
```

But if I run this other:

```
select zona
     , fid
     , count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z
join geo_bcn_illes i 
on SDO_CONTAINS(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
where zona='z01'
group by zona, fid
having fid = 53
```

The results are incoherent:

```
 zona   fid count(*)
 z01    53  10
```

Any suggestion?

I'm runnig `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is a bug somewhere. If I run:

```
select zona, fid, count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z, geo_bcn_illes i 
where sdo_contains(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
and zona = 'z01' and fid = '53'
group by zona, fid
```

The results are:

```
zona fid count(*)
z01 53  10
```

If I add a hit to avoid the index:

```
select /*+NO_INDEX(z, idx_geo_bcn_zones) */  zona, fid, count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z, geo_bcn_illes i 
where sdo_contains(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
and zona = 'z01' and fid = '53'
group by zona, fid
```

There results are correct:

```
zona fid count(*)
z01 53  34
```

:-(